# Can anyone help me identify this sound my guitar is making?

Tags: electric-guitar

My guitar has this weird reverberating sound after I strum a chord? Is this normal?

Comment: I can't notice anything particularly abnormal. It's slightly out of tune maybe? Or do you mean the low notes being a bit muddy when they sound together? Is the same problem with all chords - if you play barre chords higher up the neck, or other kinds of voicings/fingerings?

Comment: It's the reverberating sound that lingers after a strum. It's the sound a cymbal makes when you drop it on the ground and it rolls around before falling flat. Same across the neck. Doesn't what chord I play. Idk maybe it's normal.

Comment: It sounds normal to me.

Comment: Is your guitar acoustic?  It should "reverb".

Comment: Electric. Just wanted to make sure because I don't hear this sound when I hear recordings of other people. Wonder why that is

Comment: @alliang if you are playing through an amp, you might have a slight bit of reverb dialed in on the amp.  You should be able to change that with the knobs on your amplifier.

Comment: I can hear a steady 'whistle' three or four octaves above the root note. Is this what you mean? It can be heard on its own just after the last chord dies out. Sounds like an amplifier resonance. It shouldn't be there. It might be just a teaspoon ratting in a mug near the mic, but if it's always there then something is wrong. .  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Normal.

What you're hearing is the peaks and valleys of the sound waves misaligning. If your guitar is slightly out of tune and you play the same "note" in two locations (like "A" on your open "A string" + "A" at the 5th fret of your "E string") you will hear this wobble more clearly. Some may also describe it as a Leslie effect (rotating speaker cabinet). As you re-tune the strings more accurately, you'll notice the wobbles / reverberations start to align until they effectively disappear.

Unfortunately due to the nature of Equal Temperament and the guitar, some chords will do this more than others, even when you are "in tune."  But there's nothing wrong with your instrument. In fact, some find this sound is desirable :)